# Magento - Show image that ist NOT base, small_image or thumb

Tags: magento

i wonder if there is a way to show images of products that are NOT either base, small_image or thumb. I have a few hundred generated products with no selection, so i want to show an image even though there is nothing selected.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you should not try this approach.

The best solution is to run a script on your database and setup default images for all those products with none.

Here is the script:

```
# Brings all products with no standards images
SELECT * 
FROM catalog_product_entity_varchar 
WHERE entity_type_id = 4 
    AND attribute_id in (85,86,87) # base image = 85, small_image = 86, thumbnail = 87
    AND value = 'no_selection';

# update images
UPDATE catalog_product_entity_varchar t1
SET t1.`value` = (
    SELECT t2.`value` 
    FROM catalog_product_entity_media_gallery t2 
    WHERE t2.attribute_id = 88 AND t2.entity_id = t1.entity_id
    LIMIT 1)
WHERE t1.entity_type_id = 4 
    AND t1.attribute_id in (85,86,87) # base image = 85, small_image = 86, thumbnail = 87
    AND t1.`value` = 'no_selection';
```

Cheers,

Comment: That actually did not work out of the box. It says that 215 Objects were changed (mySQL), but i have around 900 products.